# Python3 : openCV setup in Ubuntu 16.0.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu, opencv3.0

I am trying to install OpenCV on my laptop. I followed the instruction in the link http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/

When I run the code in Step 4 :

```
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules \
    -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

I am supposed to make sure that it displays

```
Python 3 :

Interpreter : /home/Me/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python3
Libraries :/usr/lib/x86_64....
numpy : "the address of Numpy"
packages path : lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Instead , it displays just

```
Python 3:
--     Interpreter:/home/Me/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)
```

I cannot see any link to the libraries, numpy or the packages path. Without them, I cannot install OpenCV. I made some researches on internet, and it was not fruitful. Any help would be welcome.

EDIT : It might be helpful, I installed Anaconda , then downgraded it to the version 3.5.0

Comment: so have you tried `workon cv` and re-run the build as the tutorial suggests?

Comment: Yeah... You know just for Numpy, I tried workon cv, then "pip install numpy". The installation seemed to be successuful, yet when I run cmake, I still cant see the line with Numpy

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sudo apt install python3-opencv`
or for Windows:  `pip3 install python-opencv`